# Exclude results from array that contains ONLY the sent query. MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, reactjs

I'm trying to build a Query that excludes results from an Array when it only contains the String sent in the Query.

I have these two Arrays

Array 1

```
[ { _id :'first', subCategory : '5K'}, { _id : 'second', subCategory : '10K'}]
```

Array 2

```
[ { _id :'first', subCategory : '5K'}]
```

I want to exclude JUST the second one, so I can't use

```
query.$and.push({ subCategory: { $nin: '5K }});
```

I tried this, but it didn't work either :

```
query.$and.push({ subCategory : { $elemMatch : { $nin : '5K' }}});
```

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.

```
query.$and.push({ array : { $all : [{ $elemMatch : { subCategory : { $nin : '5K' }}}]}});
```